# Update com chave foreingkey

Tags: php

Estou com problema pra editar uma chave *foreign key*.  O código recebe o `id`, mas não consigo passar o `id` da *foreign key* para o *value* usando *inner join*. Rececebo esta mensagem:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`impacto`.`pessoa`, CONSTRAINT `pessoa_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_tp_pessoa`) REFERENCES `tp_pessoa` (`id_tp_pessoa`))' in C:\AppServ\www\impacto\user\Pessoa\action_pessoa.php:263 Stack trace: #0 C:\AppServ\www\impacto\user\Pessoa\action_pessoa.php(263): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\AppServ\www\impacto\user\Pessoa\action_pessoa.p

```
// pagina edicao
<?php
require 'conexao.php';

// Recebe o id do cliente do cliente via GET
$id_cliente = (isset($_GET['id_pessoa'])) ? $_GET['id_pessoa'] : '';

// Valida se existe um id e se ele é numérico
if (!empty($id_cliente) && is_numeric($id_cliente)):

    // Captura os dados do cliente solicitado
    $conexao = conexao::getInstance();
    $sql = 'SELECT id_pessoa , ds_nome , ds_departamento FROM pessoa 
    as a inner join  departamento as b on a.id_departamento=b.id_departamento

    WHERE id_pessoa = :id_pessoa';
    $stm = $conexao->prepare($sql);
    $stm->bindValue(':id_pessoa', $id_cliente);
    $stm->execute();
    $cliente = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);


endif;

?>  
<form action="action.php" method="post" id='form-contato' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
  <!-- area de campos do form -->


    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
      <label for="name">Nome </label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?=$cliente->ds_nome?>" name="ds_nome">
    </div>


          <div class="col-xs-2">
                 <label for="ex1"> Departamento</label>



                <?php
try{
     $conexao = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=impacto', 'root', 'cons2000');
     $conexao ->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
 ?>
<select name="id_departamento"  class="form-control">

// o problema é que nao consigo passar o id_departamento para  dentro do value
<option  value="<?=$cliente->id_departamento?>"><?=$cliente->ds_departamento?> </option>

<?php
     $sql_admins = $conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM departamento where id_departamento=id_departamento order by id_departamento ");
     $sql_admins->execute();

     while($admins = $sql_admins->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){


    echo '<option value="'.$admins['id_departamento'].'">'.$admins['ds_departamento'].'</option>';
      }
   ?>
     </select>

                    </div>



                    <input type="hidden" name="acao" value="editar">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id_pessoa" value="<?=$cliente->id_pessoa?>">

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id='botao'> 
                      Alterar
                    </button>
                    <a href='listar_pessoa.php' class="btn btn-danger">Cancelar</a>
                </form>
            <?php endif; ?> 


////pagina action.php
<?
if ($acao == 'editar'):



            $sql = 'UPDATE pessoa SET ds_nome=:ds_nome id_departamento=:id_departamento
             ';
            $sql .= 'WHERE id_pessoa = :id_pessoa';

            $stm = $conexao->prepare($sql);
            $stm->bindValue(':ds_nome', $ds_nome);  
            $stm->bindValue(':id_departamento', $id_departamento);
            $stm->bindValue(':id_pessoa', $id_pessoa);
            $retorno = $stm->execute();

            if ($retorno):
                echo "<div class='alert alert-info' role='alert'>Registro editado com sucesso, aguarde você está sendo redirecionado ...</div> ";
            else:
                echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>Erro ao editar registro!</div> ";
            endif;

            echo "<meta http-equiv=refresh content='3;URL=listar_pessoa.php'>";
        endif;
```

Comment: Não é relacionado a PHP, mas sim a MySQL, provavelmente o ID que você está tentando colocar não está cadastrado na tabela que liga a forekey a sua consulta.

Comment: quando  eu removo o inner join e troco o ds_departamento por id_departamento o update  funciona. , porem eu preciso que o ds_departamento apareca no no meu select tambem .

Comment: Precisa mostrar como as tabelas estão montadas pra entender melhor o que está acontecendo, pela query em si não dá pra saber direito, como eu disse é relacionado a mysql e não php, seu código não tem nada de errado. Mas como eu disse antes, tu tá atualizando uma linha na tabela "pessoa" que precisa estar relacionada ao id_departamento e na sua tabela departamento PRECISA existir o id que você está tentando cadastrar e seu erro é no UPDATE e não no SELECT

Answer (score 0):

Você não esta selecionado o id do departamento na query com o Join por isso o value vem em branco, certo ?

```
$conexao = conexao::getInstance();
  $sql = 'SELECT 
  id_pessoa, 
  ds_nome, 
  ds_departamento,
  b.id_departamento
  FROM pessoa as a 
  inner join  departamento as b on (a.id_departamento=b.id_departamento)
  WHERE id_pessoa = :id_pessoa';
  $stm = $conexao->prepare($sql);
  $stm->bindValue(':id_pessoa', $id_cliente);
  $stm->execute();
  $cliente = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);`
```

Após a linha `$cliente = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);` de um `var_dump($cliente); die();` e verifica se todos os dados que você quer pegar estão no Obj $cliente